# Which method is best to create Google Cloud VM from existing VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

1. Cloning VM from console?
   I tried this solution but changes inside VM before cloning are not available in new VM
2. Create snapshot from bootdisk and then use snapshot to create VM.
3. Use existing boot disk when creating VM from select boot disk popup.
4. Create new Image form snapshot and use that Image to create the VM.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked the best, it will be #4 (Create new Image form snapshot and use that Image to create the VM.). This will give you an option to refer to the image by family name while doing the automation. Also it will help you version the image and deprecate the older image etc.